# EmberJs: Setting a property of controller from within the view

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember.js-view

I am new to emberjs and wanted to set a controller property from within a Ember View. I have been trying to get around it but I am unable to set the controller property from the view. Here is a jsbin of what I am trying to do. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kiteg/6/. In this app, I wanted to set keyword property to value 'red' from within the sort view. Can someone help me out in getting around it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to access your controller properties from the view with

```
this.get('controller.myProperty');
```

Same for setting it

```
this.set('controller.myProperty', 'new value');
```

And here is a correct fiddle : http://jsbin.com/natusuro/1